# Migrating EBS volumes from gp2 to gp3 will it affect the existing file system? or do we have to change the file system?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops

Migrating EBS volumes from gp2 to gp3 will it affect the existing file system or do we have to change the file system?

Comment: No. You don't have to do anything in terms of the file system.

Comment: i had a lot of research on this but i was not able to find any thing on the file system changing

Comment: If you are not sure, why not just try it on a dummy instance with some test volume? It would be faster then asking on SO probably:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When modifying the Amazon EBS volume type from gp2 to gp3, the *contents* of the disk will remain unchanged.

The hardware used to provide the EBS volume will change, but there will be zero impact to the content of the EBS volume.